# How to make rsync delete destination directories no longer existing at source?

Tags: rsync, file-permissions, directory

I have hard drive that I back up with rsync to a network-attached storage. There are some non-empty directories at the destination (the nas) that do not exist on the source anymore. It is not a permission issue.

I had a mount issue on the OS.

The --delete option does work. The --force option (without the --delete) does not report any more diretory deletions (--progress option).

```
rsync -raz --progress --delete --ignore-errors --exclude-from='exclude_list.txt' {source} {destination}
```

Comment: try to use the rsync with the delete options, man rsync can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command

```
rsync -ravzX --delete <source> <destination>
```

Comment: What does the X do?

Comment: It preserves extended attributes.

Comment: Is X a replacement for 'g' and 'o'?

Comment: i am not sure.but i use X only

Comment: X doesn't work. It's not recognized. Maybe that's an issue with my rsync version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation but just synchronizing a *master* and *slave*:

```
rsync -rpogt --delete ${origin} ${destination}
```

Comment: I don't understand your syntax. What do the $-signs do?

Comment: @jjack is just to must replace `${origin}` with your source and `${destination}`with your destination, like for example: `rsync -rpogt --delete /home/ /nfsnas/home/`